# Android recording an apps sound output

Tags: android

Hello guys I have a question

I have to admit before I ask my question I never used Android Sdk before but I have coded java for couple of years.

I have a fm radio app.It's an internet radio and I want to record it's output. Is it possible to use an external app to record some other app's output? And if yes, It also has some pre recorded shows which you can listen within the app. They do not get saved into my device when I listen however is it possible to download those shows? Like finding source of the audio and downloading it using my external app.

I'm pretty sure that the recorded shows are downloaded from the internet. I know some audio grabbers as browser extensions in Pc. So I'm asking, if such thing is possible in Android as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25741006/850347
Seems to be currently there is no way to achieve this. I have read this article and it suggests to recompile the Android source code with some changes.

Or, you can use visualizer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816052/850347
The closest API available to you for these purposes is Visualizer. Which only captures "partial and low quality audio content".

Comment: Is it at least possible to see where does an app access.. like a packet capturer for android apps?

Comment: Yes... and I suggest you to use android visualizer. By first link I wrote, you need to recompile android platform.

Comment: The problem is I can't.. its a new handset and I don't want to root it just to void warranty.. might do it in bluestacks tho thanks for the idea ;)

Comment: Hmm... How about download another radio app that has "Recording" function? (But I still want to know how to record android output sound, too) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audials

Comment: Or, you can install Android emulator on your PC (for example, bluestack) and record sound. http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-news-discussion/350531-any-android-apps-can-record-internal-audio.html