# Speech to text recognition

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is it possible to convert mp3 files into text without playing it using the microphone, for example, when listening to an audiobook with the mobile device? I was looking for relevant API in IBM Watson but can't find the solution.

Comment: Google has a nice API

Comment: From Google cloud speech to text documentation :Real-time Streaming or Prerecorded Audio Support
Audio input can be streamed from an application’s microphone or sent from a prerecorded audio file (inline or through Google Cloud Storage). Multiple audio encodings are supported, including FLAC, AMR, PCMU, and Linear-16.

Comment: @PatrickSturm thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thereis no good/direct way to grab the audio output on android.
[Record Android Audio Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output)

For Speech to Text you could use the Google API

Although if you have the mp3, it should be no problem to convert it to text with Google API.

[Take a look here for that.](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize)