# How to record microphone and media player in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, record, microphone

I need to record mic and media player together .it work.but when I connect handsfree in the device only record mic.i need to get media player voices and record it with mic.
I need to mix voices from the media player and mic together

```
  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
                recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Music/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".amr")
                recorder.prepare()
                recorder.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support internal audio recording after android 7.0
Android only supports audio recording via microphone

[refer this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/81vhvm/android_7_has_made_recording_internal_audio_while/)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output)

Comment: but some app with api 28 record internal sounds

Comment: I don't think it does because google has removed the feature due to security issues