# how record audio internal speakers like play multiple song in app then record internal spekars voice in android studio

Tags: audio-recording

how record audio internal speakers like play multiple song in app then record internal spekars voice in android studio

i try audio capture but still not work this code apply

```
           if (!isRecording) {
            try {
                File audioFile = new File(AUDIO_FILE_PATH);
                audioOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(audioFile);
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE, AUDIO_CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
 audioRecord = new AudioRecord.Builder()
                    .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT)
                    .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                            .setSampleRate(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE)
                            .setEncoding(AUDIO_FORMAT)
                            .setChannelMask(AUDIO_CHANNEL_CONFIG)
                            .build())
                    .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
                    .build();

            if (audioRecord.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                audioRecord.startRecording();
                isRecording = true;
                btn.setText("Stop Capture");
            }

                startMediaProjection();
                startRecordingThread();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Record Android Audio Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output)  Android 10 has an API to do this, but not before.