# Is it possible to get the audio from a a third party audio player and record it with my apps?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I want to make a feature on a app which can record music from a third party music player app playing in background. Is it possible i can get the stream data from that music player which are sent to speaker? Need help

Comment: this question is too broad. you need to ask more specific questions

Comment: I wanted to transmit live video along with background music + user's voice at the same. But when i tried to record my own voice on my phone while playing a music in the background , it made the media player stopped. I searched in Stack some say it is possible like these 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125139/android-get-device-overall-audio-output-in-pcm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output
i have used Visualizer class but it's not what i want. I want full audio output so that the quality maintain

Comment: @rakeshkashyap It's actually quite clear and specific...