# Couldn't hear incoming voice in recorded calls in android 7?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, mediarecorder, call-recording

I am developing an `Android` app for recording calls.
This is my code snippet.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setOutputFile(file_path);
```

This is working perfectly for devices **below** android 7, but when I use Android 7 mobile devices **I can hear only outgoing voice but cannot hear incoming voice**.

Can anyone help me in fixing it?

Answer (score 4):

Use `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` as AudioSource as it is
microphone audio source tuned for voice communications such as VoIP, [as described on Android Developers site.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html)

I tried using `VOICE_CALL`(Uses audio uplink and downlink recording) but it can be used only by system components only, So mic is only option to record audio.

TRY:
1: Sliding up the volume during call.
2. DO NOT use headphones as audio will not be recorded by mic in some cases[Haven't tried this].
3. Works on Moto G4 Play, Android version 7.1.1(most of Motorola phones have two mics):

`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);`

Comment: I think the problem lies with the phone you are using, as you are able to record outgoing voice. The mic placement on your phone is in such a way that it can't record incoming in normal mode. Did you tried using speakerphone?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem is that you only record the microphone input with that code, which is obviously just the outgoing voice. To also record the incoming voice, you'd have to also record system sound.

To record system sound, you'll have to google a bit. Here are some stackoverflow links that should get you started:

- [android get device overall audio output in pcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125139/android-get-device-overall-audio-output-in-pcm)
- [How to record phone calls in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android)

In the end, you'd also have to merge the two soundtracks into one file to have the whole call as one.

Comment: That must have a different reason, because the code you posted only records microphone input sound.

Answer (score 2):

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

try using this

Comment: Tried this in pixel 2 with Android P, the output file does not have any content.

Answer (score 2):

this code works like a charm for Android 7 built with API 25,

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: Ends with exception "start failed." in pixel 2 with Android P.