# Outgoing voice is not getting recorded in Android version 7.0

Tags: android, call, android-7.0-nougat, recording

I am trying to record calls using Mediarecorder,but this is not helping out to record outgoing voice is not getting recorded in Android Version 7.0 only. Its working fine with 5.0,6.0,8.0. But not on 7.0. Kindly help me solve this.
Below is my code. And tried all encoders and audio sources. None helped. And yeah, added onrequestpermission too.

```
int i = audiomanager.getRouting(2);
    audiomanager.setMode(2);
    audiomanager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
    audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    int j = audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(0);
       if(j < 0)
       j = 1;
       int k = j / 2 + 1;
       audiomanager.setStreamVolume(0, k, 0);
       audiomanager.setRouting(2, 11, 15);
       recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
       recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
       recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435539/cannot-hear-incoming-voice-in-recorded-calls-in-android-7

Comment: did you tried to use `setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);` ? and VOICE_UPLINK or VOICE_DOWNLINK

Comment: @VadimEksler yeah.. Have tried.. But no luck..

Comment: and another encoder?

Comment: yeah tried.. Its recording only one voice