# How to save Reverb Effects Video in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg, audioeffect

I am working on an app that has a reverb feature. I know we can achieve this feature by the PresetReverb and EnvironmentalReverb classes.

For customization, we have the EnvironmentalReverb class and I am using this class like this and effects can be noticed in the video in real-time.

```
val eReverb = EnvironmentalReverb(1, simpleExoplayer?.audioSessionId!!)
        eReverb.reverbDelay = 5 // [0, 100] done
        eReverb.roomLevel = -1000 // [-9000, 0]
        eReverb.reverbLevel = 2000 // [-9000, 2000]
        eReverb.decayHFRatio = 1000.toShort()
        eReverb.decayTime = 10000
        eReverb.density = 1000.toShort()
        eReverb.diffusion = 1000.toShort()
        eReverb.enabled = true
        val auxEffectInfo = AuxEffectInfo(eReverb.id, 1.0F)
        simpleExoplayer?.setAuxEffectInfo(auxEffectInfo)
```

I want to **save the applied reverb effect video in the Android local storage.** I have searched if the FFmpeg framework can help, but didn't able to find **except for aeecho.**

Please help, how can I save the video with reverb effects or the ways to save the reverb effects video?

Comment: Can you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30157272/4516027)?

Comment: No, @kesh. That solution is not helping to save Reverb effects videos in Local Storage.